# Oracle Merge vs Select then Insert or Update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

What is faster?

the Merge statement

```
    MERGE INTO table_name 
     USING dual
     ON (row_id = 'some_id')
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET col_name = 'some_val'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (row_id, col_name)
     VALUES ('some_id', 'some_val')
```

or

querying a select statement then using an update or insert statement.

```
    SELECT * FROM table_name where row_id = 'some_id'
```

if rowCount == 0

```
    INSERT INTO table_name (row_id,col_name) VALUES ('some_id','some_val')
```

else

```
    UPDATE table_name SET col_name='some_val' WHERE row_id='some_id'
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The *rule of thumb* is, if you can do it in one SQL, it'll generally perform better than doing it in multiple SQL statements.

I'd go with the MERGE if it does the job.

Also - another suggestion: you can avoid repeating data in your statement, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO table
 USING (SELECT 'some_id' AS newid,
               'some_val' AS newval
        FROM dual)
 ON (rowid = newid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET colname = newval
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (rowid, colname)
 VALUES (newid, newval)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but how about the process on the oracle server?

Comment: yes, I gathered that - but I was talking about the choice of column name, which conflicts with oracle's ROWID pseudocolumn.

Comment: Don't know why my answer survived so long with inaccurate information. Live and learn, I guess.

Comment: If I use host arrays in PRO*C code for doing bulk merge with similar query, will bulk merge better that doing a query first and then do insert/update in bulk using host arrays? Please comment.Will it degrade performance as the volume increases?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana, you're more likely to get a useful answer by asking a new question. Plus, it's free!

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yes I did, it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167241/oracle-proc-bulk-merge-of-records-in-c-using-host-arrays-degrading-performance

Comment: The question is which one is faster? It is not which one is easy to write

Comment: @MayurB, that's precisely the question I answered. That's what "perform better" means.

Answer (score -2):

Take care of the merge. It can consume a lot of your area `TEMP` using `HASH JOIN`. Test him using hint `FIRST_ROWS` or use `UPDATE` view join plus `INSERT` with `NOT EXISTS`.